# Redirect only the first time and store the visitor's ip

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code but when it enters ips.text, it only checks the first ip that is the number 0 and the others it leaves it does not verify them and I need help.

```
$ipArray = file('ips.txt');
    foreach ($ipArray as $ipTest) {
      if (substr_count($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],trim($ipTest)) != "0") { 
        die("HELLO IP LOCKED");
      } 
      else {
          header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    };
      } 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); {
    $archivo="ips.txt"; $proceso=fopen($archivo,"a") or die ("error en el sistema"); 
    $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; $fecha= date("d/m/y"); 
    $datos="".$ip."\n";
     fwrite($proceso,$datos); 
    fclose($proceso); 
    }
```

Comment: remove the `die("HELLO IP LOCKED");`

Comment: it does not store the ips when it was deleted

Comment: Are you sure `$ipArray` is array with all the ips? can you please share its content (example)? why it the `;`  after the `else` block? and why compare with `"0"` (string) and not `0` as integer?

Comment: if I do not compare it as "0" it does not store the ip and then else because if it does not pull me error I'm sorry I do not know much about php, so I ask for help

Comment: and how I make sure that iparray is a matrix with all the ips

Comment: Add `var_dump($ipArray)` before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$ipfile = "ips.txt";
$ips = explode("\n",file_get_contents($ipfile));
$isban = 0;
foreach($ips as $ip) {
    $ip = explode(" ",$ip,2);
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip['0']) {
        $isban++; 
    }
}
if(!empty($isban))
{
    die("IP IS BANNED!");
}
else
{
    $ips[] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." ".date("d/m/y");
    $ips = implode("\n",$ips);
    file_put_contents($ipfile,$ips);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
    exit;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: What about `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`?

Comment: I you want to use those charset, add it before the `header('Location: http://www.google.com');`

Comment: I know it - But its part of the OP code so it need also to be in yours

Comment: Also notice OP didn't write the date to his ips file (don't know why but can be intentional) so if you add that to ips file note it and explain why

Comment: thanks for your help if silvio and everyone who uses this code thank you

Comment: and do not write the date because foreach was not reading the ip in ips.text if it had any other character